# Shape error only when TPU training Keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tpu

First off, this is not my code. I just changed it to be able to train it on TPU. The original author is [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-generate-music-using-a-lstm-neural-network-in-keras-68786834d4c5). I am able to run it on the GPU accelerated runtime on a collaboratory notebook but it seems to break when I do TPU accelerated runtime.

Here is my [notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1fCfB9osSTUM3FsB0cggUYJon6GMvSm91). It just give me an error that the activation function is not the right size.

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected activation_21 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (205,)
```

I would appreciate any help I can get as I spent like 3 hours debugging.

Comment: As it seems the labels are not sparse, therefore you need to use `'categorical_accuracy'` (or more succinctly `'accuracy'`) as the **metric**.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works now! How do I give you the bounty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are one-hot encoding the labels and therefore they are not sparse, you need to use 'categorical_accuracy' as the metric:

```
model.compile(..., metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])
```

or more succinctly use 'accuracy' to let Keras infer the right metric based on the loss function used (which in this case would be `'categorical_accuracy'` since you are using `categorical_crossentropy` as the loss function):

```
model.compile(..., metrics=['accuracy'])
```